# Try to show data from db using JPA and EJB

Tags: servlets, jpa, ejb

I try to display data from my database, but I get 500 error page: javax.ejb.EJBException. I don't understand why it's not working. Maybe my Bean is wrong? Please help me.

Warning in Glassfish log: WARNING: WARNING: EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB SearchBean, method: public java.util.Collection com.stark.logic.SearchBean.searchByNumber(int)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "buy")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Buy.findAll", query = "SELECT b FROM Buy b"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Buy.findByIdBuy", query = "SELECT b FROM Buy b WHERE b.idBuy = :idBuy"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Buy.findByNumberBuy", query = "SELECT b FROM Buy b WHERE b.numberBuy = :numberBuy")})
public class Buy implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id_buy")
private Integer idBuy;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "number_buy")
private int numberBuy;
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "buy")
private Product product;
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "buy")
private Client client;
//getters & setters
```

EJB BEAN:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class SearchBean {

@PersistenceUnit
EntityManagerFactory emf;
EntityManager em;

public Collection searchByNumber(int number){
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
    Query searchQuery = em.createNamedQuery("Buy.findByNumberBuy");
    searchQuery.setParameter("number_buy", number);
    List list = new ArrayList();
    list = searchQuery.getResultList();

    return list;
}
}
```

Servlet:

```
@EJB
private SearchBean searchBean;


@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws    ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    String num = request.getParameter("number");
    int number = Integer.parseInt(num);
    List list = new ArrayList();
    list = (List) searchBean.searchByNumber(number);
    Iterator it = list.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        Buy buy = (Buy) it.next();
        out.println(buy.getProduct());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter name in @NamedQuery and in setParameter() method must be equal:

```
searchQuery.setParameter("numberBuy", number);
```